# Integrate an existing app to my own app

Tags: android, android-studio

I almost finished working on my project.Now I want to integrate an open source app into my project. Is there any way to achieve that in android studio?

I found two ways to do this by converting it as a library project  or transferring it as a new module in the existing project.But I am not able call activities in the new app from my main activity. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to make some changes in existing project to use it as a library...

Comment: there is no way of doing that you need to merge them manually..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya how can I merge them manually.

Comment: @SweetWisherツI dont get it..Can you explain it?

Comment: Merging it manually means create a new project and just copy paste the classes-packages from both project into one..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya Thanks :). I thought the same

Comment: Have you added your library project as dependency in your main project?